# Is it possible to combine multiple arrays using linux command line?

Tags: command-line, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

I'm wondering if I can create a table or file in which I can fill it with elements from other files as the following illustration:

**cat_table_1/file1**

1 cat

2 scooter

5 ball

6 coffee

---

**cat_table_2/file2**

1 dog

4 rain

5 street

7 Monday

---

**cat_table_3/file3**

1 police

6 chain

7  bike

---

**cat_table_Combined/create_new_file**

1 cat  dog   police

2 scooter empty  empty

3 empty empty  empty

4 empty  rain  empty

5 ball street  empty

6 coffee  empty  chain

7 empty Monday  bike

Unfortunately, I'm not so strong in programming so if there any way to do that using the command line I will prefer it.
Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Think you will need to provide expected file outcome at this point - hard to say - also cat_table_{n} is the actual folder names or are you doing cat table_1

Comment: First of all, thank you for the prompt response. Those tables were an example.  What I would like to do is to combine 3 tables results in 1 in the format of my example. More specifically, I want to make a gene comparison of 3 different databases.My aim is to generate a table that includes the gene number and the corresponding information from the 3 databases. For instance,                    gene 1  reference from DB 1,  ref from db2 (if there is any),  ref from db3 
gene 2  ref from db1,               ref from db2,                           ref from db3 
.......
gene xxx

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/awk/awk_basic_examples.htm is a good place to start - you can use more complex commands to iterate through files/folders such : ` find . -name some-pattern\* -exec ls -l  {} \; -exec grep something {} \;`  - to find and execute your awk statement - I suggest first looking at 1 file trying to use awk to get the pattern u need then to wrap it either around a 1 liner like above or writing the steps into a shell script - this is how any shell/bash script starts

Comment: Ok i see!!!!  Thank you sooo much for the guideline, for the tutorial and for your time.